# Phone not reading headphone jack resistance

Tags: headphone-jack

So I wanted to modify a pair of headphones I have to work with my android phone (Motorola Droid Turbo), and to do so I was experimenting with resistor values according to the "Wired Audio Headset Specification (v1.1)"

https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/specification.html

I wired up a 240 ohm and 470 ohm resistances which should control volume up and volume down, respectively. I plugged in an old headphone jack I spliced, and double checked the voltage output which was reading the correct 2.2 V. Unfortunately when I tried connecting the 240 ohm and 470 ohm across nothing happened. I tried this with my friend's android phone (LG G3) and it worked perfectly. Not really sure where to proceed from here.